# Ignore Soft-Deleted records within graph

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

Using EF Core

Assuming Structure:

```
class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    List<GrandChild> Grandchildren { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}

class Grandchild
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public int ChildId { get; set; }
}
```

Records could have been soft-deleted at any level, although no descendant of a soft-deleted entity can itself not be soft-deleted (obviously).

```
List<Parent> nonDeletedParents = Context.Parents
    .Include(p => p.Children).ThenInclude(c => c.Grandchildren)
    .Where(p => !p.IsDeleted)
    .ToList();
```

will get me non-deleted parents, but how do I exclude deleted children and grandchildren in a single query to the database?

One approach I have explored is to use an anonymous return type and then rebuild:

```
var result = await Context.Parents
    .Where(p => !p.IsDeleted)
    .Select(p => 
    {
        Parent = p,
        AllChildren = p.Children
                      .Where(c => !c.IsDeleted)
                      .ToList(),
        AllGrandchildren = p.Children
                           .Where(c => !c.IsDeleted)
                           .SelectMany(c => c.Grandchildren)
                           .Where(g => !g.IsDeleted)
                           .ToList()
    }).ToList();

List<Parent> actualResults = new List<Parent>();
results.ForEach(r =>
{
    Parent actualResult = r.Parent;
    actualResult.Children = r.AllChildren;
    actualResult.Children.ForEach(c => 
    {
        c.Grandchildren = r.AllGrandchildren.Where(g => g.ChildId == c.Id).ToList();
    });
    actualResults.Add(actualResult);
}

return actualResults;
```

But, seems pretty inelegant.  Is there a preferable approach?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for Global Query filter? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters

Comment: Interesting!  Thank you, @SvyatoslavDanyliv.